# Why does Pip give me an error message even though I have it installed?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to download a module for Python with pip in terminal, but every time I try to use pip3, I get this error message (copy/pasted):

```
pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip3
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What can I do?

I tried running commands to check if pip3 was installed and got the same error message, but I have downloaded the newest version of Python.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: What terminal? A [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) window on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)?

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426779/what-to-do-about-question-with-multiple-low-quality-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You're on Windows. Try running Python with command `python` or `py`. If that works, you have Python in your Path. You should try `pip` instead of `pip3`.

Comment: I've tried both

Comment: @ANdrew like the answerer has said, you need to have python in your environment variables